# Reverse geocoding Problem

Tags: android, geocode

my below code doesn't give any result.

```
list_addr = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 5);
```

even not returns `null` value...

it behaves like dumb.

give me solution for that.

Comment: what does it return ?    what values are latitude and longitude ?

Comment: latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude_edtxt.getText().toString());
    longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude_edtxt.getText().toString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Geocoder.getFromLocations(double, double, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)) either returns a result (even null is a result) or throws an exception.

Are you silently catching generic exceptions somewhere in your code?

**Update:**

Use this code and then check the logcat. It should give you a reason why this does not work:

```
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> list_addr = gc.getFromLocation(40.0d, 10.0d, 5);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        Log.e("Geocoder IllegalArgumentException exception: ", iae.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("Geocoder IOException exception: ", ioe.getMessage());
    }
```

**Update2:**

This turned out to be a bug in Emulator v2.2: [Android; Geocoder, why do I get "the service is not available"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619924/android-geocoder-why-do-i-get-the-service-is-not-available)

Comment: And what do you do when you catch an exception? Silently ignore it?

Comment: javadoc says: "The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

Comment: Also, Geocoder needs internet access. Did you request permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @peter : yes i have requested for permission in menifest file.

Comment: i enter 23.03957 and 72.56600

Comment: @peter : it returns null. and error is "service is not available"

Comment: If you are trying it on emulator 2.2, then it might be a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619924/android-geocoder-why-do-i-get-the-service-is-not-available

Comment: oh ya...thx for memorizing me that...now itz working in better way...thx a lot...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Address> addresses = new Geocoder(MyActivity.this,Locale.getDefault()).getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```