# What is the best way to interpret user's location beside Geocoder

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoder

So I made an app which access the user location and then interpret (reverse geocoding) it with the Geocoder like this:

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, maxResults); 
Address address = addresses.get(0);
town = address.getLocality();
countryCd = address.getCountryCode();
```

However I find the geocoder service to be really unreliable with IOException and service unavailable too often.

I've read solutions involving spamming the Geocoder service until it gives a result, and others says the service will only allow one hit per IP addr every 15 seconds.

Sometimes rebooting my device will make the service available again.

Is there another API or approach to this subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a solution there: 
[android problem to get latitude & longitude from a given address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476371/android-problem-to-get-latitude-longitude-from-a-given-address)

> Just to mention an alternative, you can use the Google Maps' REST
>   based [reverse geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/v2/#ReverseGeocoding). You can probably use this as a fallback. As
>   you would be using Google Maps in your app too, you should be good
>   with the API rules.

Comment: the api rules are pretty strict - 2500 requests a day for geocoding

Answer (score -1):

```
public void getAddress(double lat, double lng) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        String add = obj.getAddressLine(0);
        GUIStatics.currentAddress = obj.getSubAdminArea() + ","
                + obj.getAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.latitude = obj.getLatitude();
        GUIStatics.longitude = obj.getLongitude();
        GUIStatics.currentCity= obj.getSubAdminArea();
        GUIStatics.currentState= obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getCountryCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getSubThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // TennisAppActivity.showDialog(add);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Use it may be help full to you.

Comment: this is the same api as above in my OP. Please read before answering, the geocoder.getFromLocation is throwing the IOException.

Answer (score -1):

Your probably getting IOException and ServiceUnavailble due to your implementaton.

Have a read of this best practice : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

(It's better than an API) and opensource!

Comment: I've already read that 2 times. This is not helping as it differs from my question. This is not about getting the location. My Location is correctly acquired and updated but I can't interpret it without the Geocoder.