# Android google apis 10 geocoder within emulator problem: service not available

Tags: android, android-emulator, geocoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android; Geocoder, why do I get “the service is not available”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619924/android-geocoder-why-do-i-get-the-service-is-not-available)

After several hours of searching for the solution to my problem, also on this forum I decided to ask it here.

The function geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); throws exception: "java.io.IOException: Service not Available". Many people encountered this problem, but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Is it simply not possible in the emulator?