# maps not working in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, android-maps

I am using the following map class to use maps in my android app...

```
 package com.wglxy.example.dash1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class map extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapview;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private Button map1;
    String[] myadd;
    private int len;
    private GeoPoint p;
    private MapController controller;
    private TextView helloText;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private int i;
    private String[] mynames;
    private ImageButton info;
    private String[] citysearch7 = new String[1];
    private ImageButton search;
    private ImageButton home;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        myadd = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strings");
        mynames = intent.getStringArrayExtra("names");
        info = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.info);
        search = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search1);
        home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.hom);
        len = myadd.length;
        System.out.println("Length=" + len);
        mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    //  check();
        while (i != len) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Coming inside try catch and adress="
                        + myadd[i]);

                addresses = geocoder
                        .getFromLocationName(myadd[i].toString(), 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Catching");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                p = new GeoPoint((int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6),
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));

                controller = mapview.getController();
                controller.setZoom(12);

                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(map.this, p, mynames[i]);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapview.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                controller.animateTo(p, new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        controller.setZoom(12);
                    }
                });
                mapview.invalidate();

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(map.this);
                adb.setTitle("Google Map");
                adb.setMessage("Please Provide the Proper Place");
                adb.setPositiveButton("Close", null);
                adb.show();
            }
            i++;
        }

    }

    void check() {
        info.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AboutActivity.class));
            }
        });
        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), start.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        search.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.bloodmenu:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), search.class));
            break;
        case R.id.bankmenu:
            citysearch7[0] = "";
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    searchbank.class);
            intent.putExtra("search", citysearch7);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.updatemenu:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), update.class));
            break;
        case R.id.registermenu:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), register.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("name", "");
            b.putString("house", "");
            b.putString("street", "");
            b.putString("city", "");
            b.putString("blood", "");
            b.putString("phone", "");
            b.putString("file", "register");
            intent1.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

but it gives an error. The log of which is as follows:

```
D/dalvikvm(  466): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 8171 objects / 631112 bytes in 54ms

D/dalvikvm(  466): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6139 objects / 371288 bytes in 55ms

I/System.out(  466): Length=3

I/System.out(  466): Coming inside try catch and adress=Surya Nagar Agra

I/System.out(  466): Catching

W/System.err(  466): java.io.IOException: Service not Available

W/System.err(  466):    at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocationName(Geocoder.java:159)

W/System.err(  466):    at com.wglxy.example.dash1.map.onCreate(map.java:68)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

W/System.err(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

W/System.err(  466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

W/System.err(  466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

W/System.err(  466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

W/System.err(  466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

W/System.err(  466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

D/AndroidRuntime(  466): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm(  466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(  466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wglxy.example.dash1/com.wglxy.example.dash1.map}: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at com.wglxy.example.dash1.map.onCreate(map.java:75)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

E/AndroidRuntime(  466):    ... 11 more

W/ActivityManager(   70):   Force finishing activity com.wglxy.example.dash1/.map

W/ActivityManager(   70):   Force finishing activity com.wglxy.example.dash1/.search

W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{44efd6a8 com.wglxy.example.dash1/.map}

W/ActivityManager(   70): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44ed9bb8 com.wglxy.example.dash1/.start}

W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44edc6e8 com.wglxy.example.dash1/.search}

W/ActivityManager(   70): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{44efd6a8 com.wglxy.example.dash1/.map}

D/dalvikvm(  275): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1903 objects / 139672 bytes in 196ms

D/dalvikvm(  407): GC_EXPLICIT freed 119 objects / 9440 bytes in 130ms

D/dalvikvm(  416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 635 objects / 50232 bytes in 145ms

D/dalvikvm(  196): GC_EXPLICIT freed 808 objects / 45672 bytes in 176ms
```

Please consider the print statements that I have used and using that could anyone please help me understand my problem?? I also changed my key and updated but in vain. Is there something wrong with my emulator, I also tried creating a new fresh emulator but it still doesn't work. Also i have commented the line which calls the check() method, is there a problem if i do not comment it?
-Please help...thanks in advance.

Comment: com.wglxy.example.dash1.map.onCreate(map.java:75)
That line is causing a null pointer. Check that.

Comment: @blessenm Line 75: if (addresses.size() > 0) {
it seems that addrresses is NULL...but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have searched for the error..and you will find many like

[Android; Geocoder, why do I get "the service is not available"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619924/android-geocoder-why-do-i-get-the-service-is-not-available)

and

[Why is Android Geocoder throwing a "Service not Available" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761052/why-is-android-geocoder-throwing-a-service-not-available-exception)

Comment: I tried the links that you provided and in the following link i found my exact problem.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816
i tried the solution given in comment#21 but it doesn't work for me. Could you please suggest me what should i do to continue my android app development further?

Comment: Your app and code is ok...just try to run once in actual device rather than in emulator

Comment: I tried and it works on the actual device, but could you please suggest me some solution for the emulator cause i dont have the actual device of my own.

Comment: hmmm..may be you will have to try with lower android versions like 1.6(emulator/project api) level I think it will work..

Answer (score 0):

It is specified in the [APi docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) that geocoder can return null if doesn't find any match.

Try it in an actual device like frankenstein mentioned. Or if you are using an emulator, make sure it uses the google api's.

Answer (score 0):

If your minimum SDK setting permits it, try running on an API level 7 emulator, it should work OK,

Comment: I tried to launch an API level 7 emulator through eclipse, but it doesn't start up. It gives the error as follows...
emulator: ERROR: unknown skin name 'WVGA800'

Comment: I dont understand all my platforms have been downloaded properly.