# Get Location Name by passing Latitude and Longitude in android

Tags: android, gps, ioexception

I have written following code for getting location name :

**UseGpsActivity.java**

```
public class UseGpsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        boolean gps_is_enabled = false;
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> accessibleProviders = mlocManager.getProviders(true);
        gps_is_enabled = accessibleProviders != null
                && accessibleProviders.size() > 0;
        Log.v("gps enabled", gps_is_enabled + "");
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        // mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(mlocManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
        // mlocListener);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mlocListener);
        // mlocManager.set
    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", 5000)
                    .show();
            Log.v("gps", "gps disabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", 5000).show();
            Log.v("gps", "gps enabled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
            String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = "
                    + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(UseGpsActivity.this,
                    Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                        loc.getLongitude(), 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addresses != null) {
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    Log.v("Addresses : ", addresses.get(0).getLocality() + "");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Addresses : " + addresses.get(0).getLocality()
                                    + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v("gps", Text + " " + addresses.get(0).getLocality()
                            + "");
                }
            } else {
                Log.v("addresses ", "NULL");
            }
        }
    }/* End of Class MyLocationListener */
```

**Code on Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="demo.usegps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".UseGpsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When i use geo fix (`geo fix -122.084094 37.422006`) i get toast displayed with lat and lng , but i get following message on logcat :

```
01-19 13:32:48.991: W/System.err(751): java.io.IOException: Service not Available
01-19 13:32:48.991: W/System.err(751):  at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:117)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at demo.usegps.UseGpsActivity$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(UseGpsActivity.java:74)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:191)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:124)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:140)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-19 13:32:49.001: W/System.err(751):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-19 13:32:49.011: W/System.err(751):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-19 13:32:49.011: W/System.err(751):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 13:32:49.011: V/addresses(751): NULL
```

Which service do i need to add or call in my code ??

Comment: If you are trying it in Emulator then its a bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619924/android-geocoder-why-do-i-get-the-service-is-not-available

Comment: yes i am trying on emulator 2.2 but on real device its not even showing toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Following code and now I am able to get the name of location :

```
public class GPSLocatorActivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        // enable Street view by default
        mapView.setStreetView(true);

        // enable to show Satellite view
        // mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
        // mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16); 
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

                /* Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                        " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                mapController.animateTo(point);
                mapController.setZoom(16);

                // add marker
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.clear();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
                String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mapView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
            String address = "";
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                        address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return address;
        } 

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;
        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            // convert point to pixels
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

            // add marker
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.red);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null); // 24 is the height of image        
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get address

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ lat+ ","+ lon+ "&sensor=true";
            String res = IOUtils.MakeRequest(url);
            Log.e("result", res);
            if (res != null && !res.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(res);
//              if (jObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                    JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    if(jArray.length() > 0){
                        JSONObject geo = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        address = geo.getString("formatted_address");
                        String[] splite = address.split(",");
                        if(splite.length > 3){
                            String temp = splite[2];
                            temp = temp.substring(0,3);
                            address = "";
                            address+=splite[0]+","+splite[1]+","+temp+","+splite[3];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            address="No Address";
                        }
                        Log.e("address", address);


                    }

//              }
```

Comment: He is not doing a URL request for an address, hes using the GPS. Also just posting code is not an answer...